# fadeOut and fadeIn for dropdowns - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project and I have multiple drop downs that are populated using PHP.  Each dropdown is given an id of `styleDrop` and a container id of `styleCont`.  Now for some reason, on the first dropdown, that is the only one that seems to be 'registered' with my code:

```
//this file is used for the styling dropdowns
$(document).ready(function () {
    //close opened dropdown and open one selected:
    $("#styleDrop").click(function(){
        var selected = $(this);
        $("#styleCont").fadeOut();
        selected.closest("#styleCont").fadeIn();
    });

});
```

What is suppose to happen:

User will click a drop down and if any other dropdown is open, it will close, while the one the user just selected opens.  Also if they click outside the dropdown it will close.

The problem is this will not work on any of the other dropdowns and on the one it works with, it just makes it open and close right away.

I am not sure as to why this is.  Thoughts? Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs are supposed to be unique.

Your selector is finding the first one (by calling getElementById) and returning it.

Use a class instead and change your selector appropriately to use ".styleCont"

```
<select class="styleDrop" ... >
```

And then...

```
$(".styleDrop")
```

Comment: Hmmm forgot about that, by chance is their a way around this by using ID?

Comment: This isn't the right way to do it - but you could use getElementsByTagName("select") or $("select"), loop through them all and check the presensce of this id, then bind your click listener

Comment: Actually could I use a div class that the select box is inside?

Comment: Why the resistance to using a class?  And yes, then you would use $(".myDivClass select").

Comment: I could just use the classes that are defined on the dropdowns but that's adding a lot more code.  So just checking what my best option is.

Comment: Hey I changed it to `class='whatever styleDrop`' and the for same thing for the `styleCont`.  Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

> Each dropdown is given an id of styleDrop

That's why, ids must be unique for every element on a page, so your function only binds to the first one it finds in the DOM. Use a class instead (i.e., `.styleDrop`).